# Validating Schema.org 'Question' markup in SDTT

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have been using Schema.org to markup a FAQ section inside my articles. One year ago the Google Structured Data Testing Tool was not showing any error. However now show 2 errors.

> Question:
> name - A value for the name field is required.
>
> WebPage / FAQPage
> mainEntity - A value for the mainEntity field is required.

The Microdata I am using is:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <div itemprop="text">
    <main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage http://schema.org/FAQPage">
    </main>
    QUESTION
  </div>
  <div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">ANSWER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don’t get these errors when testing the snippet. I only get two warnings: "Missing a FAQPage …" and "Missing a QAPage markup …".

Comment: Sorry I pasted the old html, already corrected with the html that I was using until now.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FAQPage">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <div itemprop="name">QUESTION</div>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
      <div itemprop="text">ANSWER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <div itemprop="name">QUESTION2</div>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
      <div itemprop="text">ANSWER2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google sometimes changes some requirements for the structured data, here you can only be on the safe side if you test it regularly. In your case it seems that the Question itself is missing for google: At least the first error is easily fixed, I tried fixing the FAQPage error but somehow I couldn't get it yet. I will try a bit more and edit my question if I find a good solution!

Edit: I couldn't get it to work fully but what I found out so far: Here is a [FAQ Page example](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=microdata&utm_source=faq-page) from google itself, it seems you have to wrap the faqPage around all questions. And have the mainEntity of type Question. Maybe with this example you can change your markup to get the desired result.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <div itemprop="text">
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage http://schema.org/FAQPage">
<div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
</div>
</div>
<span itemprop="name">QUESTION</span>
</div>
  <div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">ANSWER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For regular automated testing, I would recommend using the screaming frog program in which you can connect an API for SDTT. At one time we solved a similar problem by adding itemprop = "name" to the questions. Below is an example of a page where the validator has no comments at the moment: https://fixly.pl/kategoria/pozostale-uslugi-tapicerskie/radomsko .

Example of code:

```
<div class="l4Category__seo">
    <div class="l4Category__seoText">
        <div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 itemprop="name">question</h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <div itemprop="text">
                        <p style="text-align:justify">The answer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 itemprop="name">question</h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <div itemprop="text">
                        <p style="text-align:justify">The answer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 itemprop="name">question</h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <div itemprop="text">
                        <p style="text-align:justify">The answer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The answer should go with some code and explanation. Your post should go as a comment.